# Can't parse HashSet to JSONObject String

Tags: java, json

I am trying to Convert `HashSet<String>` to `JSONObject` and then Parse the output JSON.

Here is what I have tried:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("set", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b")));
json.put("list", Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
String jsonString = json.toJSONString();

System.out.println(jsonString);

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject afterParse = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
System.out.println(afterParse.toJSONString());
```

But it's giving me this output and error:

```
{"set":[b, a],"list":["a","b"]}
Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character (b) at position 8.
```

Here, you can see both a and b are strings, in the list both are inside double quotation marks but in the set it's not.

I am using `org.json.simple` v1.1.

Comment: Did you try to make your HashSet as a HashSet<String> ? I think it will not solve the problem, but it worth being tested.

Comment: I have tried using HashSet<String> but the output is same

Comment: When I changed the package to `org.json.JSONObject`, same code works. Not sure it may be a bug in org.json.simple.

Comment: when u convert a array of strings to list and then the list to a Set, it is no longer String, but an array of objects hence `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b")));` gives `"set":[b, a]` (without quotes). And `parser.parse(jsonString);` works on `Object` not `array of Objects.`

Comment: I have changed this ```json.put("set", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b")));``` to ```HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add("a");
        set.add("b");

        json.put("set", set);``` but not working

Comment: do u expect a `{"set":["b", "a"],"list":["a","b"]}` ?

Comment: HashSet is a collection, just use list.

Comment: `json.put("set", new Arraylist<>(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"))));` this works fine then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a problem with `org.json.simple` library.

I have used `org.json` library, and have to do some minor changes in above code to work:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("set", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b")));
json.put("list", Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
String jsonString = json.toString();

System.out.println(jsonString);

JSONObject afterParse = new JSONObject(jsonString);
System.out.println(afterParse.toString());
```

The output of this code is:

```
{"set":["a","b"],"list":["a","b"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

when u convert a array of strings to list and then the list to a Set, it is no longer String, but an array of objects hence new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"))); gives "set":[b, a] (without quotes). And parser.parse(jsonString); works on Object not array of Objects.

Try using a list instead of a set as below :

```
json.put("set", new Arraylist<>(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"))));
```

Comment: i know that if i convert set to list it will work. but i wanted to convert HashSet to JSON directly

Comment: @Ashraful Islam  , converting Hashset which is a collection to json will give error with json simple parse method. Using a object like List will do the deal .

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution is use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

```
   String str = "str1";
   String str2 = "str2";
   String str4 = "str3";

   Set<String> setObject= new HashSet();
   setObject.add(str);
   setObject.add(str2);
   setObject.add(str4);

   ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
   String JSON = mapperObj.writeValueAsString(setObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, here HashSet converts to JsonArray, and now this array put into the JSONObject using any key refer below cup of code.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("A");
set.add("B");
set.add("C");
set.add("D");

// Conver to JSONArray
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(set.toArray());

// JSONArray to JSONObject with Key
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("List", jsonArray);

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

// Output:
// {"List":["A","B","C","D"]}
```